# SQL Jobs error for SSIS package of access data import

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

I am tearing my hair out with this particular issue, I have used SQL Agent Jobs for years and know there can be issues with permissions which I have always got around. But this issue I can't fathom. I am importing data from an Access Database to SQL Server via a SSIS package, I have had it successfully run via a SQL Job with no problem (using a proxy account). I need to change the login that runs the jobs, this has been set up with the same permissions and runs various jobs like running stored procedures. But when it tries to run the SSIS package it will not have it and I get a failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. It has exactly the same permissions, so why would it fail when I change the windows login account for the proxy? Any help would be hugely appreciative

Comment: Does the new account have the same permissions for the Access database as well?

Comment: How about file permissions to the MS Access file?

Comment: Does this apply to you? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramoji/2009/03/10/the-acquireconnection-method-call-to-the-connection-manager-failed-with-error-code-0xc0202009/